# How can i detect category page on Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I want to detect virtuemart category page in mod_breadcrumbs.

Breadcrumbs is loading all page and i just wanted write a message in category page.

My breadcrumbs code:

```
 <div class="breadcrumbs<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php 
        echo '<ul>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
            // If not the last item in the breadcrumbs add the separator
            if ($i < $count -1) {
                if (!empty($list[$i]->link)) echo '<li><a href="'.$list[$i]->link.'" class="pathway">'.$list[$i]->name.'</a></li>';
                else echo '<li class="pathway">' . $list[$i]->name . '</li>';
                if($i < $count -2) echo ' <li class="pathway separator">></li> ';
            } else if ($params->get('showLast', 1)) { // when $i == $count -1 and 'showLast' is true
                if($i > 0) echo ' <li class="pathway separator">></li> ';
                echo '<li class="pathway">' . $list[$i]->name . '</li>';
            }
        } 
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can check if you're on a category view:

```
$appInput = Jfactory::getApplication()->input;
if($appInput->getCmd('option')=='com_content' && $appInput->getCmd('view')=='category' ){
//add your code here
}
```